# OSX Sierra doc moves itself to another monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, dock

When running two external monitors in OS X Sierra, my dock sometimes changes which display it is located on.   Is there a setting to stop this from happening?  This happens at random times, and I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Brian, please be more specific. When does it switch screen? Is there any time in particular? Please give more details.

Comment: It's totally random.  Happens to me every week or so.

Comment: Do you unplug your external monitor a lot?

Comment: Yes but mostly at the end of the work day.  Not the power cord, but the display adaptor (thunderbolt?)

Comment: So the dock switches monitor about every week?

Comment: Yes. Roughly once a week.  I unplug the monitors and it resets it, but I'd rather not have to do that.